# Past Imperfect with "died"

Tags: grammar, past-perfect, tenses

Is this sentence correct?

"I wracked my brain, trying to put the timeline together. **Just minutes before *she’d died*, Lara had gone to the flower shop down the road.**"

Or just it be: "I wracked my brain, trying to put the timeline together. **Just minutes before *she died*, Lara had gone to the flower shop down the road.**"

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *died*. Two clauses with verbs in the pluperfect (past perfect) make the sentence confusing. Incidentally, the expression is *to wrack one's brains*, not *braining*.

Comment: Haha! I added "I wracked my brain" to give context to the sentence, but thank you for pointing out the error! And thank you for the answer.

Comment: If we're issuing corrections, the expression is _I racked my brain_. The OED lists four verbs _to wrack_, but three are marked as obsolete and the fourth as "archaic or dialect".

Comment: To brain someone would be to remove or damage their brains, or to attack their head as if you were attempting to do so. "As the sentry passed, George brained him with a large rock."